# Choosing objects from a set of N objects, where the probability of one object being chosen is not independent of another object being chosen

Tags: algorithm, probability

**Context:** I have a neural network, which, for a card game, tries to predict what the opponent's hand is. It outputs a probability for each card and probabilities for various pairs of cards that I expect to have dependent probabilities (I assume the rest of the pairs to be independent and therefore, just equal to the product of the probabilities of the two cards involved). Given this information, I want to be able to sample possible opponent hands, and I believe solving the following problem would allow me to do so.

**Problem:** There are **N** objects and we will be choosing a set of objects, which I will refer to as **S**, from them. Let **P** be an **N x N** matrix such that **Pij** is equal to the probability that **S** contains both object ***i*** and object ***j*** (This means **Pii** just represents the probability that **S** contains object ***i***). Given this information, what is an algorithmic approach to sampling possible resulting sets, given this probability distribution over the **N** objects.

Originally, my network outputted only a probability for each card, and I just assumed that each of the cards were independent. In this case, I could easily sample possible hands, by just picking cards according to the distribution (after normalizing it so that the probabilities added to 1) and then updating the distribution to exclude cards that have already been drawn.

In this case, however, in addition to updating the probabilities of cards, I also need to update the probabilities of pairs when a card is added, and I'm unsure how to go about doing that.

I'm willing to make assumptions if they are necessary, similar to how I assumed all of the cards were independent in the simplified case, and I'm open to a non-iterative approach if there is one. Any help would be appreciated.